# Installing 32 bit Windows 7 Guest Virtual Machine on 64 bit OSX Host

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox to attempt to install 32 bit Windows 7 Pro as guest on a 64 bit OSX 10.8.5 host.

Windows attempts to load its setup program and throws an error:

"Windows failed to start..."

"File: \windows\systme32\boot\winload.exe

Status: 0xc000035a

Info: Attempting to load a 64-bit application, however this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode."

I've tried disabling VT-x and it made no impact.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a legit Windows 7 32-bit ISO? If so, there are some serious issues...

If this is a custom made ISO, it's likely loading the 64-bit installer, and just giving the software for 32 bit Windows. If you have the CD key, you can check the other threads for downloading the legit Windows 7 ISO from Microsoft, and make sure you choose the 32-bit version.

Comment: I downloaded a fresh ISO and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it helped you.